# How to dispay mutliple times same form with Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to display many times the same Form because the user can create multiples time a Task in the same Page (I manage this with Jquery and Ajax).
When I try to do that with Form factory, only one form is displayed.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an embedded collection of forms:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I want to display the same form mutliples times, I don't understand how to do that with collection of forms. The form I want to display is not include in other form.

Comment: With the extremely limited information you gave, that's all I have for you.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help. I find how to resolve my problem.